# How to connect WAMP to Google SQL with Cloud Proxy

Tags: wamp, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

On our development server and test linux boxes, we have been using Google SQL with Cloud Proxy for connections.  Everything is working just fine.

However, I need to setup a couple users with WAMP.  (Windows 10 64bit Apache, PHP 7).  I am not very familiar with WAMP.  We have everything working except Cloud Proxy.

On our Linux boxes we have the socket setup in its own folder (under root) /cloudsql.

What is the equivalent location on WAMP?  (We don't want to have to maintain different configuration files just for one or two WAMP boxes).

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you must use TCP sockets. The documentation can be found here:
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app#6_start_the_proxy

Specifically you must tell the proxy the instance name and the local port on which to listen for connections for that instance:

```
cloud_sql_proxy.exe -instances=<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>=tcp:3306
```

Comment: Keep getting error: google: could not find default credentials.

Comment: Are you specifying -credentials_file on Linux? you should do the same on windows.

Comment: I not sure I have the right syntax since when I do, I still get the error

Comment: if you're using -credentials_file, the default credentials error should not matter. does the proxy start? have you tried connecting to it?